# Correct initialisation of GLEW using glewInit?

Tags: opengl, glew

In my software I'm generating a dummy window in order to query Windows various pixel formats, then destroying that window and then creating a new window after selecting the appropriate format.

After initialising the first window, I initialise glew with glewInit() in order to use the wglChoosePixelFormatARB function.  Although after destroying the dummy window, extensions continue to function, I'm aware this isn't technically "correct", as in theory it's possible for two windows to have two different sets of function pointers.  Therefore I want to initialise glew a second time, after creating the second window.

When I do this I get errors from ordinary functions thereafter, such as this:

```
GLint viewport[4];

::glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
```

, with glError being 1280 - although strangely, when I check viewport, it seems to contain the correct values (I'm looking at glGetError() to see if the previous command caused an error).

So, my question is this:  with the two state OpenGL initialisation you seem to need for Windows (create dummy window, initialise extensions, use extensions, destroy dummy window, create actual window), how do you initialise glew the second time when the new window is the current context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomment destroying the dummy window/context only after you created the main window. Also, as Slicedpan alread suggested, you need only a hadfull of extension functions, so I'd load those manually to not rely on GLEW. Also did you make sure, your second call to glewInit() is after you made your proper OpenGL context has been created *and* made current on the thread GLEW functions are about to be used?

Comment: I did, yes.  It's definitely active.  I'm thinking that you're right about fetching the extensions myself.  Looking at things I need to store them per window in any case (to be certain it's correct).  GLEW supports glewContextInit, but that looks like a pain to use as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve a function pointer for wglChoosePixelFormatARB first (using wglGetProcAddress, I think), then after the second window is created initialise glew.